# .NET MAUI: Display svg-image file on iOS

Tags: ios, .net, maui

Noticed, that svg-files, added to .NET MAUI project, to the folder `Resources\Images\` do not display properly on iOS, while displaying ok on Android.

I use declaration:

```xml
<Image Source="myFile.svg" />
```

for image located at: `Resources\Images\myFile.svg`

And while it is displayed on Android, it does not show the image on iOS.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon referencing these files, do not specify the `svg` extension.

Instead of

```xml
<Image Source="myFile.svg" />
```

Use

```xml
<Image Source="myFile" />
```

It works ok on iOS and Android.

In some cases it would be good to specify `HeightRequest`, `MinimumHeightRequest`, `WidthRequest` and `MinimumWidthRequest` to display image properly.

Comment: the *Resizetizer* that MAUI uses behind the scenes during the build converts all image resources to the PNG format, so the common way to access the file is by using the *.png* extension: *myFile.png* would work as well.

Comment: Thank you. I think using `*.png` extension while there's no such file in Resources/Images can be confusing for developers.